# Remove redundant edges from a set of (x,y) coords

Tags: python, loops, set, coordinates

I have a set of coordinates: `set([(1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)])`

I need to get rid of redundant edges. For this example, there is one redundant edge: `(1,4)`. It is redundant because there is already an edge from `(1,3)` and `(3,4)`.

How should I lay out a loop (I was thinking it might need to be triple nested) to check for redundant edges in this set and remove it from the set?

Comment: This is about graph connectivity, in that you can remove `(1,4)` and the graph will still be connected. Basically, you are looking for a [spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree) for your graph.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is the set of the points. Unless you know which points are connected and which are not, you cannot remove anything, point (1,4) can form an edge with (2,4) and if you remove it, the edge will be gone as well.

Moreover, (1,4) is not in the middle of edge from (1,3) to (3,4) -- draw the points on a piece of paper and see for yourself.